# Create a button that opens a questionnaire that then gets attached to the opportunity record

Tags: custom-button

I've been asked to create a button on the opportunity object that will open a questionnaire with about 20 questions and gets saved to the related opportunity record. The questionnaire will not be used every time, so it somehow has to show that it was used. It can be a Word template if that's the best we can do, but what they really want is something created within Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new Custom button for Opportunity
- Choose Context Source as Url
- Insert your Url in the big text area below

  ```
  /apex/NewQuestionnaire?opportunity_id{!Opportunity.Id}
  ```
- On the receiving end catpure the Opportunity Id and relate it to the questionnaire in Apex Controller

  ```
  questionnaire.Opportunity__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('opportunity_id');
  ```